# Resize Column Width QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have this widget created with QTableWidget:
[image]

and I would like that the column of my table resize in order to occupy the entire width of the widget, while for the rows is ok as it is.
I know there is a similar question like mine but I was not able to solve it in that way..
This is my code

```
void MainWindow::createTable(int rows, int columns) {
    mainList = new QTableWidget;
    QStringList headerLabels;
    headerLabels << "Title" << "Director" << "Year" << "Counter" << "Rating";
    mainList->setRowCount(rows);
    mainList->setColumnCount(columns);
    mainList->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headerLabels);
    mainList->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked | QAbstractItemView::SelectedClicked);
    mainList->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    mainList->resizeColumnsToContents();
    mainList->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

    setCentralWidget(mainList);
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Considering that you are using Qt5, give a try to

```
QTableWidget* mainList = new QTableWidget;
QHeaderView* header = mainList ->horizontalHeader();
header->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

OR

There is a header flag to ensure that the QTableView's last column fills up its parent if resized.

```
header->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

Comment: I'd just add that if you want to have non-last column take all remaining space you should write: "ui->table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(columnIndex, QHeaderView::Stretch);"