# column width in QTableWidget and PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, qt4, pyqt4

I have a QTableWidget and I want to make sure that all the columns are stretched, i.e occupy all of the form. The solution that I found is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23215842/1636521) but it seems to be for `Qt5` and `C++`. I'm working with `PyQt4` and `Python`. Is there a way to do this in `PyQt4`?

Answer (score 0):

the function for PyQt that is similar to that and which also apply to QHeaderView  is :

```
setResizeMode (self, ResizeMode mode)
```

with possible values for resize mode

```
enum ResizeMode { Interactive, Fixed, Stretch, ResizeToContents, Custom }
```

more information :

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qheaderview.html

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what I need. Each cell is of equal size except the size of the headers. That somehow stayed fixed. I looked at the API and didn't find anything that could help (I certainly could have missed something). Do you know what could be the issue?

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm not able to understand what is the issue. Can you provide a screenshot please?

Comment: [Here is the image](https://imagebin.ca/v/2vJ5JGFHoS7P) The header columns, the one that has `GPIO` is not the same size as others. It would be nice to make all of them equal. How do I do that?

Comment: try setDefaultSectionSize (self, int size)